# Tomcat thread count gets increased only

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpoolexecutor

I have created simple web application with JSP-Servlet hosted on Tomcat 7. As per my requirement, I need to create 2 background threads which will keep checking their respective shared Queues with some time duration and if it find any element in their respective queues it will process that element.

For this 2 continuous thread management, I have used **java.util.concurrent.Executors**. It works fine for me but the issue is, **java.lang.Thread.activeCount()** gets incremented only when I do some operation to add elements in resource queues. Also when I check with Java VisualVM, it shows the thread count increased continuously.

Following are my code segments:

Web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>InvokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>InvokerServlet</display-name>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-class>com.test.servlet.InvokerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

This is startup my InvokerServlet at the time of tomcat start, which will initiate the threads:

InvokerServlet.java:

```
public class InvokerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(InvokerServlet.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public InvokerServlet() {
        super();
        log.debug("Initiate thread invoking");
        new ThreadInvoker().invokeThreads();
    }
...
...
}
```

ThreadInvoker.java:

```
public class ThreadInvoker 
{
    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
    Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();

    public static Queue queue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
    public static Queue queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

    private static ExecutorService executor = null;
    private static volatile Future result1= null;
    private static volatile Future result2 = null;

    public void invokeThreads()
    {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("----> " + java.lang.Thread.activeCount());
            try
            {
                checkTasks();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkTasks() throws Exception
    {
        if(queue1.size() > 0)
        {
            result1 = executor.submit(t1);
        }

        if(queue2.size() > 0)
        {
            result2 = executor.submit(t2);
        }
    }
}
```

Thread1.java

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable
{

    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            log.debug("Inside Thread1 run");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thread2.java

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable
{

    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            log.debug("Inside Thread2 run");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is why the Active thread count gets incremented when I add element in queue1 and queue2 with some external operation. Why it does not gets decremented once their respective thread gets completed their work?

Please let me know when I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use a thread pool. Its already doing what you are trying to reinvent.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're experimenting and that's not the entire code. From your code `InvokerServlet` will never finish because the constructor goes on to an endless while loop. Because, `new ThreadInvoker().invokeThreads()` will never finish.

If you wanted to see the thread count of just the executor, you should use this, and the count will not increase beyond **2** as you have configured.

```
System.out.println("----> " + ((ThreadPoolExecutor)executor).getActiveCount());
```

I hope the increasing number of threads are not executor threads but the threads which are dropping elements into the queue. If you take a thread dump, you'll know what those threads are doing and on whom are they waiting. That will give you an answer, why those threads are increasing.

You are not dequeueing from the queues - but, that shouldn't block you now. It can go until you add elements of the count `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I have checked with the code you have given and its playing with thread count between 0 and 2 only :). For InvokerServlet, yes it was not allowing to start my server so I have updated that code as well. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a thread leak in your `ThreadInvoker` class by creating new Threads `t1` and `t2`. You never start them, so they can't die.

You're also going to an infinite loop in your `InvokerServlet` constructor.

My recommendation: scrap all your code and look for a proper tutorial on servlet container background tasks. You're not the first one to want to observe a few queues.